# Best way to turn large "lazy suzan" bearing with stepper motor

Tags: stepper-motor

I'm designing an automated object capture turntable (take photos -> photogrammetry) where the platform the object sits need to rotate, driven by a stepper.

The catch is the base is glass as I need to view the object from beneath and the bearing sits around the edge of the glass plate, not at it's center.

This is the bearing I'll be ordering, it has a 24" diameter:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B071CPFCYS/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A2ZKGRENV5NC9J&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071CPFCYS)
[image]

Now I need a way to mechanically couple a stepper motor to the inside or outside of the bearing.  I'd like to use something more precise like timing belt as opposed to rollers.

Is there an existing product/technique for interfacing large wheels with stepper motors?

Update: As per  jsotola's suggestion I did some searching, best thing I could find was this:
[Scooter Wheel Adapter for 5mm Shaft](https://www.pololu.com/product/2673)
[image]

My origional ideas was to glue gt2 belt around the inside/outside, only just rediscovered the link to my inspiration: [Make Your Own Gears Out of Wood and Timing Belts](https://www.lumberjocks.com/projects/63729) 
[image]

Comment: use a friction drive roller to turn the ring .... or buy two, discard one outside ring, stack  the inside rings, use a belt drive to turn the inside ring .... paint timing marks on inside of inside ring ... use optical sensor to detect marks

Comment: Or make your timing marks on the glass and don't use a stepper at all; use a servo motor instead.

Comment: yeah, i was thinking "no stepper", but i did not say it

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Geordie, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: The "best" way to do something is the way that meets all of your criteria. Are you asking how to *couple* a motor or are you asking about *resolving* a position? Stepper motors are only precise when they never experience a load greater than their holding torque - if they slip then you've blown the only advantage they have. How precise do you need to be? How quickly do you want to change positions? You said *in your question* that you'd like to use "something more precise like timing belt as opposed to rollers," so why not use a timing belt?

Comment: If you're looking for feedback on something, or lists of suggestions, etc., please join us in [chat] - all the off-topic content is welcome in chat. As it stands, though, you've asked for a recommendation for the "best" way to do something, with no criteria on what would make a suggestion "good," and you've supplied an answer in your own question with no explanation as to why that's not a suitable answer. There's no clear answer to this question other than lists of suggestions and so it [is not a good fit for the site](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Have a machine shop make you big gear or timing belt pulley that fits over the outside of the bearing.

Note that if you a position reference on the outer edge of the glass you can use encoder feedback and a DC motor -- you should be able to achieve more precision this way.